# javascript string replace &#8217; with '

Tags: javascript, regex

This seems like a simple problem but I can't seem to find the solution (or one that works) anywhere.

I have the following string:

"REDEACTED is a REDEACTED, REDEACTED, which focuses on the research and development of REDEACTED.
It has 3 main brands, REDEACTED, a REDEACTED, and REDEACTED, a therapeutic line. It’s last brand is a REDEACTED line, which is set to be sold to REDEACTED offices.
Through its subsidiaries, REDEACTED and REDEACTED, REDEACTED is able to cultivate, process and develop its REDEACTED through the 2 company’s facilities, which are located in REDEACTED.
Though it hasn’t sold any of its product yet, it plans to solidify partnerships in the near future.
"

and I'm trying to replace all instances of ’ with '.

I have tried things along the lines of

```
 newText = newText.replace("/'/gi", "'")
 newText = newText.replace("&#8217;", "'")
 newText = newText.replace("/&#8217;/gi", "'")
```

with no real luck, any suggestions?

Comment: Try this `newText.replace(/'/gi, "'")` remove the double quotes around

Comment: You want to pass a regex literal, not a regex in a string literal

Comment: `.replace(/[‘’]/g,"'").replace(/[“”]/g,'"');`

Comment: Oh the issue was I wasn't removing the single quotes in the replace statement (this did the trick): newText = newText.replace(/&#8217;/g, "'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess when using a real regex you need to remove the single quotes in the first parameter. Think this did the trick: newText = newText = `newText.replace(/&#8217;/g, "'")`

Comment: It helped me ..Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this way to simply remove that `’` with `'`?

```js
const regex = /’/ig;
const str = `REDEACTED is a REDEACTED, REDEACTED, which focuses on the research and development of REDEACTED. It has 3 main brands, REDEACTED, a REDEACTED, and REDEACTED, a therapeutic line. It’s last brand is a REDEACTED line, which is set to be sold to REDEACTED offices. Through its subsidiaries, REDEACTED and REDEACTED, REDEACTED is able to cultivate, process and develop its REDEACTED through the 2 company’s facilities, which are located in REDEACTED. Though it hasn’t sold any of its product yet, it plans to solidify partnerships in the near future.`;
const subst = `'`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log("Substitution result:\n", result);
```